# Cannot configure RestKit with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I did setup my project to use RestKit and CoreData: added CoreData framework in 'Link binary with libraries' and "pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'" to my Podfile.

Everything looked fine until I tried to use RKObjectManager's method

```
managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:
```

Xcode gives me the following error:

**No visible @interface for 'RKObjectManager' declares the selector 'managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:failure:'**

There is a #ifdef RKCoreDataIncluded preprocessor directive before this method in RKObjectManager.h, and RKCoreDataIncluded is defined this way:

```
#ifdef _COREDATADEFINES_H
#if __has_include("RKCoreData.h")
#define RKCoreDataIncluded
#import "RKManagedObjectStore.h"
#import "RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.h"
#endif
#endif
```

I can't figure out what else do I need to do to enable CoreData in RestKit?

Comment: Please post the code that is calling that method, along with the setup of your moc and RKObjectManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out in order to use RestKit with CoreData you have to create precompiled header file for your project and add the following line:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1564

Comment: The order in the PCH file matters now whereas it did not before. I scratched my head on that for a while after updating RestKit before I realised.  The import for CoreData has to go before the import for RestKit.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, RestKit expects that Core Data has already been imported. Therefore, simply import Core Data before RestKit:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

There's no need to create a precompiled header, which would create a dependency between the libraries and every single class in your target.